# How to run a vim command from the shell command-line?

Tags: bash, shell, vim, zsh

There are many stackoverflow questions about running shell programs from within `vim`. Is it is possible to do the reverse, i.e.,

```
$ vim :BundleInstall
```

to allow me to run [BundleInstall](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) as part of a shell script, rather than having to open `vim` and run it manually?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Note, now the syntax has changed, and the line should read (As per [@sheharyar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1533054/sheharyar)):

```
vim +PluginInstall +qall
```

For posterity, previously, the correct line was:

```
vim +BundleInstall +qall
```

Should anyone other than me be looking! Note: this is in the [Github README](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) for vundle.

Comment: **If** you need to pass arguments: `echo '{"foo":"bar", "baz":{"baa":0,"bao":1}}' | vim "+setf json" -`

Comment: To execute multiple commands, e.g. for vim-plug: `vim +PlugInstall +PlugClean! +qall`

Answer (score 36):

Per the [vim man page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/vim1.html) (`man vim`):

> ```
> +{command}
>
> -c {command}
>     {command}  will  be  executed after the first file has been
>     read.  {command} is interpreted as an Ex command.   If  the
>     {command}  contains  spaces  it  must be enclosed in double
>     quotes (this depends on the shell that is used).   Example:
>     Vim "+set si" main.c
>     Note: You can use up to 10 "+" or "-c" commands.
> ```

or:

> ```
> --cmd {command}
>     Like using "-c", but the command is  executed  just  before
>     processing  any  vimrc file.  You can use up to 10 of these
>     commands, independently from "-c" commands.
> ```

It really depends on what you want to do. Also, as described at the [vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) readme file, if you launch vim like this:

> ```
>     vim +BundleInstall +qall
> ```

This will install all bundle options without opening vim.
And just for clarification, from the [vim documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_08.html):

> ```
> :qall
>
>     This stands for "quit all".  If any of the windows contain changes, Vim will
>     not exit.  The cursor will automatically be positioned in a window with
>     changes.  You can then either use ":write" to save the changes, or ":quit!" to
>     throw them away.
> ```

Answer (score 5):

How about something more complex?

```
vim "+set ff=unix" "+wq" node_modules/less-monitor/bin/less-monitor
```

Not sure whether that is totally correct, but it works for me. 
Thanks @jvc26

Comment: I can't understand whether this is a new question (which should then be asked separately) or a new answer.

Comment: It's just an example how to use the solution with multi-word command like `+set ff=unix` and with `+wq` instead of `+qall`. In my case I need to update the file. I posted this as answer just because I can't post a comment (50+ reputation needed)

Answer (score 2):

I'll add another answer for people who are looking for a more general solution.

`vim +command` works to run one Vim command but to run several Vim commands from a shell.  Instead, start Vim in Ex-mode and supply commands with a Here document.  This is an example from a script I wrote. It searches for a pattern in the file and inserts some text before it.

```
    ex --noplugin +1 "$v_file" <<-END 
            set maxmempattern=8000
            /^\s*\<endmodule\>/i

            FIXME   \`ifdef XXX_INCLUDE_API
              \`include "${api_file}"
            \`endif

            .
            w
            q
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
vim --cmd BundleInstall
```

do what you want?

Comment: You need to exec command after loading plugin. use `-c` option